# Use Async to make an GET request

Tags: ocaml

Taken from the [chapter 18](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html) of the Real World OCaml book, I'm trying to break down the example given.

My scope, to just make the GET call and print something of the JSON we get back.

This is my code ( it's supposed to be a subset of the example given )

```
(* libraries *)
open Core.Std
open Async.Std


(* Generate a DuckDuckGo search URI from a query string *)
let query_uri query =
  let base_uri = Uri.of_string "http://api.duckduckgo.com/?format=json" in
  Uri.add_query_param base_uri ("q", [query])


(* Extract the "Definition" or "Abstract" field from the DuckDuckGo results *)
let get_definition_from_json json_string =
  match Yojson.Safe.from_string json_string with
  | `Assoc kv_list ->
    let find key =
      begin match List.Assoc.find kv_list key with
      | None | Some (`String "") -> None
      | Some s -> Some (Yojson.Safe.to_string s)
      end
    in
    begin match find "Abstract" with
    | Some _ as x -> x
    | None -> find "Definition"
    end
  | _ -> None


(* Execute the DuckDuckGo search *)
let get_definition word =
  print_endline ("get_definition word:" ^ word);

  Cohttp_async.Client.get (query_uri word)
  >>= fun (_, body) ->
    Pipe.to_list (Cohttp_async.Body.to_pipe body)
  >>| fun strings ->
    (word, get_definition_from_json (String.concat strings))


(* run *)
let () =
  get_definition "OCaml"
  >>= fun (word, def) -> 
    print_endline ("- word: " ^ word);
    (
      match def with
        | None -> print_endline "[EMPTY]"
        | Some str -> print_endline str
    )
```

My issue is that I get this error when compiling:

```
ocaml setup.ml -build
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ /Users/antouank/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -c -g -annot -bin-annot -thread -package yojson -package threads -package textwrap -package re2 -package core -package cohttp.async -I src -o src/main.cmo src/main.ml
File "src/main.ml", line 48, characters 18-41:
Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
     'a Async.Std.Deferred.t = 'a Async_kernel.Deferred0.t
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
E: Failure("Command ''/usr/local/bin/ocamlbuild' src/main.native -use-ocamlfind -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

How can I get the string out of that Deferred, and what does that error mean exactly?
In the book, the example is run with a weird Command wrap, so I cannot see how to pull it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your definition of `run` is that the anonymous function

```
fun (word, def) -> 
    print_endline ("- word: " ^ word);
    (
      match def with
        | None -> print_endline "[EMPTY]"
        | Some str -> print_endline str
    )
```

is not correctly typed to be used with a monadic operator `>>=`. It has type `string * string -> unit` while the `>>=` would here expect a function of type `string * string -> unit Deferred.t`.

If you look at the example of an *echo server* in the very same chapter, it will suggest the following approach:

```
let run () =
  get_definition "OCaml"
  >>= fun (word, def) -> 
    print_endline ("- word: " ^ word);
    (
      match def with
        | None -> print_endline "[EMPTY]"
        | Some str -> print_endline str
    );
    Deferred.return()

let () =
  ignore(run ());
  never_returns (Scheduler.go ())
```

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that I have to a) run the "scheduler", whatever that does, and b) I had to "ignore the return" but I had no idea how to do it.
When I run the snippet you gave, the example works fine, but it doesn't exit. How do I tell it to exit after it's done? And where do I find more info on the `ignore` and `never_returns`?